# Crystal Reports 2011 Multiple outputs of currency

Tags: crystal-reports, report, financial

I am trying to write an output based on multiple part numbers that will display multiple price outputs.

Ive used if {ItemCode}="XXXX" then $220.00*{Quantity}

But I have about 4 different item codes and pricing outputs I need to display. Ive tried different variations but get 0.00 for all other outputs.

Comment: Is it really your formula? Looks like the syntax is incorrect. Is $220.00 really a constant? If you have 4 items codes, wouldn't it be necessary to write the else's?

Comment: yes, This was an example of what I really need to do. The database does not have any pricing in it. Just an item # and a qty. There are only 4 items I need to price out. So I have to do it manually.

Comment: May you post a print screen of your formula and a print screen of your detail secton showing the item code, the quantity and the formula result for each line?

Comment: if  {ItemCode}="7006" then $210.00*{Quantity}       This is all I have so far. Ive tried using or but get blank results. Im looking to use various itemcodes for various manual outputs. The cost is not in the system so I have to enter it manually